# Javascript variable substitution

Tags: javascript, function, variable-substitution

I have an array

```
daysoftheweek:['Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'],
```

Also I have functions

```
function totalMonday() {}
function totalTuesday() {}
```

Can I use variable substitution to call them?

```
total+{daysoftheweek[0]}
```

Comment: what do these functions? this feels like an example where one function with an argument would be the better solution.

Comment: they are actually vuejs computed values but you are right, I created a method thay takes a couple of params. Although the answer is correct I feel it is a bit messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use bracket notation on window object:

```
window['total' + daysoftheweek[0]]()
```